# Force $set instead of $set interleaving with $pushAll

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was debugging why **Array** fields of my Schema are only growing in size despite explicitly setting their length to 0 or **= [];**.

It turns out that when Mongoose sends requests to MongoDB some parts of requests have **$set** suffix while others having **$pushAll** despite some of **$set**ting values also being arrays.

How does Mongoose choose what suffix to specify? How can I force it to use **$set** for all of the updating fields?

Comment: Can you include some example code that shows how you're modifying your array properties?

Comment: @ZachB I only use accessing **array[ index ]**, assignment **array = []**, **array.push()** and **array.pop()**. Ehm, while formulating this sentence wondered if there can be any problem with **array.push()**? Can Mongoose.js somehow deduct that if I used **.push()**, then resulted MongoDB request must be **$pushAll**?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @dnickless question is mostly about how and why Mongoose.js chooses to modify array on database between **updating data by setting new value** and **appending new value to what database already have**. Cannot find anything about it on Mongoose docs, so asking. Can't see what code I'm supposed to make an example of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your mongoose version, `array.push()` is relying on [$pushAll](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pushAll/)  , so ...

> How can I force it to use **$set** for all of the updating fields?

```
array.push(whatever); //uses $pushAll
```

instead use :

```
array = array.concat([whatever]); //uses $set
```

---

**EDIT:**

You should update to the latest version (`4.11.5` at the time of writing this)

You can see @ [mongoose/array.js](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/6a571b28f424d05b5bb536d552efee8bda4cc62a/lib/types/array.js#L27)

- *Values always have to be passed to the constructor to initialize, otherwise `MongooseArray#push` will mark the array as modified.*

In the `MongooseArray Constructor` you can see is done using `concat` to avoid the `#push` mark:

```
function MongooseArray(values, path, doc) {
 var arr = [].concat(values);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Is it specified anywhere within Mongoose docs? Or somewhere in a sources?

Comment: what version of mongoose are you currently using?

Comment: I have currently installed mongoose@4.7.6

Comment: I have updated the answer with some source reference :)